# spring cloud contract add description to auto generated method

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a groovy contract like:

```
Contract.make {
        description "When login with some params authorization token expected"
        request {
            method 'POST'
            url '/xxx/yyy'
            headers {
                contentType("application/json")
            }
            body($(execute('generateBody(null, null, null, "Hi")')))
        }
        response {
            status 200
        }
    }
```

It runs as expected, the problem comes when we have about 200 similar tests on the same file, when opening the generated java test class is hard to distinguish among each test.

**Is there any way to include the `description` field inside the generated java test method?**